# original iPad not charging

Tags: ipad

Ok, I just bought a brand new original iPad. Sounds impossible, right? Well, we just opened the box, and it is not even charging. There is no indication that this iPad even works even though it is technically "new." Is this something that Apple will need to fix or do I just need to let it sit on the charger overnight and hope it wakes up from a 2 year sleep in its box?

Comment: Are you using the charger AND cable that came with the iPad. My original iPad will not charge with anything other than the parts that came with it, it is a very lame "feature."

Comment: In addition to Dave Nelson's advice: don't use a computer's USB port to charge the device, but use a wall outlet. Charging the iPad from the USB port is extremely slow.

Comment: Most *fake* chargers don't provide enough power to charge it. Be sure that you have an original one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have been using original charger, and I guess the iPad needed some time to wake up. All is good now! Appreciate the advice and will keep in mind that I should only use original charger and wall outlet in most cases.

Comment: By "original" are you referring to the first generation? Or are you referring to some unclarified non-mini version?

Comment: I never had a problem charging my 1G iPad with other cables (all official). You will be better off using the 10W power adapter that should have come with it though. When the iPad has power it will sometimes say that it is NOT charging when plugged into a laptop. This is because the laptop does not provide the required 1100MA output (see http://www.ipadmalaysialabs.com/ipad-not-charging-when-connected-to-computer-usb/).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up:

- When the battery of an iOS device is fully depleted, it needs a few minutes of charging before it turns on.
- You need to use original cable and adapter
- If charging an iPad, use the wall outlet instead of laptop's USB port when possible.

Answer (score -1):

Did you buy this from Apple? If so, have it replaced. It comes with a 1 year warranty. About the issue: Leave it plugged in over night. Sometimes iOS devices (especially iPads I've noticed) appear to be nothing more than a paper weight even after an hour of "charging". Sometimes they power back up after a while, sometimes they don't. If it doesn't, *and* it's not under warranty, I'd replace the battery.