# iPad pro 12.9 is charging but not turning on

Tags: ipad, battery, charging, ipados

My iPad pro 12.9 2‭019 was completely drained and when I plugged it in the Type C charger it showed that it is charging but it׳s been overnight and still hasn't powered back on

Comment: When deeply discharged you must use a mains charger - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89279/original-ipad-not-charging

Comment: I׳m using the original charger to charge my iPad and still no.

Comment: I'd get in touch with Apple then